# How do I read external text files with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to read an external (as in from a different domain) text file, but nothing I've tried is working. 
What usually happens is the response is `undefined`, or nothing at all.
Here's one thing I've tried:

```
// package xmlhttprequest is installed
// this was copy-pasted from some other stackoverflow question
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

txtFile.open("GET", "https://snappeathing282346239557829348747259837723489.000webhostapp.com/pin.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
      allText = txtFile.responseText; 
      lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
    }
  }
}
console.log(txtFile.send(null)) // Logs response to console
```

What I get as a response is `undefined`, how can I get 123 (123 is what the txt file contains) to be logged instead of `undefined`?

Comment: I mean.. you never logged the response.  Why would you expect logging .send() to log the response? that's... not at all what it returns.

Comment: @KevinB I honestly don't know why I thought that would work, I just plugged `console.log()` into random functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try node-fetch for example

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch('https://snappeathing282346239557829348747259837723489.000webhostapp.com/pin.txt')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(content => console.log(content))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DaveNewton and @esqew for suggesting the `fetch` api/package.
Heres the code:

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
fetchUrl("http://snappeathing282346239557829348747259837723489.000webhostapp.com/pin.txt", function(error, meta, body){
    console.log(body.toString());
});
```

and it logs 123 to the console