# Downloading a message attachment in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fs

I'm making a map loader that relies on attachments and .txt files.
I could do it with normal text, but since Discord has a character limit for each message, it doesn't work.

That's why I want to download message attachments on my local machine to process them further.

How can I download attachments from Discord messages using fs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use a simple get request to the image's url (you can get this through [attachment.url](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url)) using node-fetch then pipe the response to a .png file using fs

(If you get errors while installing node-fetch or while using the code below, try installing node-fetch v2 instead of the latest release via `npm install node-fetch@2`)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const imageUrl = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/GLD_ID/MSG_ID/IMAGE.png'

fetch(imageUrl)
    .then(res =>
        res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./path/to/image.png'))
    )
```

You can also [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565540/14688730) which goes into more detail

Comment: Yea i tried doing that. I also found another one about txt files but in both cases i get an error probably because i haven't installed node-fetch :|. Thank you.

Also is there a way i could get a text file as an attachment because thats what im going after. Thank you either way!

Comment: It should be a similar process to download a text file, and putting it as an attachment is similar to how you would attach a image to the bot's message. To download the contents of a text file, the code will be different.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997902/14688730) to get the text file, then use [fs to write it to a file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options)

Comment: Tysm smallketchup82!

Comment: I got the URL t least but it seems as though you can't use :
```js
  const smth = fetch(message.attachments.first().url);
  const atht = smth.text();

Comment: Does .text() only work with assync functions??/

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner but you should be using await. Use the [module's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#plain-text-or-html) for an example on how to do that